# Injecting services in custom ErrorHandler causes "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!" error, how can I fix this?

Tags: angular, error-handling

I have the following code :

app.module.ts:

```ts
NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule // Routes
    ],
    providers: [ // services
        AppLog,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

MyErrorHandler.ts:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor (private _appLog: AppLog) {}

  handleError(error:any):void {
    let errorMessage: string = "" + error
    this._appLog.logMessageAsJson(errorMessage, "error")
            .subscribe(
              ...
            )
  }
}
```

appLog.ts

```ts
@Injectable()
export class AppLog {
    constructor (private _http: Http) {}

    logMessageAsJson(message: string, type: string) {
        let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
        let jsonMessage = {"type": type, "message": message}

        return this._http.post(JSON.stringify(jsonMessage), headers)
    }
}
```

However, when my app bootstrap, it fails if I have an injection in `MyErrorHandler` with the following error :

```ts
Unhandled Promise rejection: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!
```

If I do remove `constructor (private _appLog: AppLog) {}` and then do something else in `handleError` it works just fine and the ErrorHandler is called.

I guess it doesn't work as AppLog and MyErrorHandler are instantiated at the same time

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this workaround to break up cyclic dependencies with DI

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  private _appLog: AppLog;
  constructor (injector:Injector) {
    setTimeout(() => this._appLog = injector.get(AppLog));
  }
  ...
}
```

Angulars DI itself just doesn't support cyclic dependencies.

Comment: The code inside setTimeout should be a function - e.g. setTimeout(() => { this._appLog = injector.get(AppLog)); });

Comment: I have an error with this solution... my object is undefined.

this.logger = injector.get('Logger');

I'm using a custom class to log. It's provide just before the custom error handler

Any idea ?

Comment: @JoeAllen hard to tell with this information. Can you provide a http://stackblitz.com example?

Comment: I just can ask for a new question here to display the code. I'll edit this to put the url

Comment: @JoeAllen I didn't see your question in the links, instead of setting it in the constructor you can get it when you need it.
`private get _appLog(): AppLog {
    return this._appLog = injector.get(AppLog);
}`

Answer (score 10):

The ErrorHandler is created before the providers. So we need Injector for dependency injection in our custom error handler class.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler{
   constructor(private injector: Injector) { } 
  handleError(error: any) {
      let router = this.injector.get(ServiceName);

    }
}
```

Create a default service via Angular cli and check the first part see `providedIn: 'root',`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomService{
  constructor(private otherService: OtherService) { // ok not failed } 
}
```

[For more detail check angular `@Injectable-level configuration`](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)

> @NgModule-level injectors
>   You can configure a provider at the module level using the providers metadata option for a non-root NgModule, in order to limit the scope of the provider to that module. This is the equivalent of specifying the non-root module in the @Injectable() metadata, except that the service provided via providers is not tree-shakable.

Comment: Thanks!! This solution gave me a hint to fix 'Cannot Instantiate cyclic dependency ! Store' error.