# Angular 2: Global AppInjector. How avoid warning "circular dependency"

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular App I have a global variable called AppInjector which returns the Injector. This variable ist set in the `AppModule`.

```
export let AppInjector: Injector;

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        AppInjector = this.injector;
    }
}
```

I have some helper functions that get with the help of the `AppInjector` a special service. The helper functions are in separate files and don't belong to any component. For example:

```
function initNodeTemplate() {

    diagram.nodeTemplateMap.add(NodeCategory.Question,
        GO(go.Node, "Auto",
            {
                click: (evt, obj) => {(AppInjector.get(MyService) as MyService).myFunction(obj)},
            },
            // other stuff ...
        ));
}
```

The problem is that the Angular compiler warns me about a circular dependency (because of the `AppInjector`. `WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\frame\frame.module.ts -> src\app\designer\designer.module.ts -> src\app\designer\designer.component.ts -> src\app\designer\helpers\templates.helper.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts`.

**How can I get rid of this warning?** 
I know that I can inject a service into a component and then pass the service to the helper function. In this case I could pass `detailService` as a parameter to `initNodeTemplate()` and so I don't need the `AppInjector` anymore. But I want to avoid messing up my function parameters with this services.

Comment: Break the cycle. Hard to tell exactly how without seeing the code that causes it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585863/angular2-injecting-services-in-custom-errorhandler/41585902#41585902

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to avoid this, is to have your classes import `AppInjector` from something different than the `AppModule` that declares/provides those very classes.

So, add a helper, e.g. `app-injector.ts`:

```js
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Allows for retrieving singletons using `AppInjector.get(MyService)` (whereas
 * `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(MyService)` would create a new instance
 * of the service).
 */
export let AppInjector: Injector;

/**
 * Helper to access the exported {@link AppInjector}, needed as ES6 modules export
 * immutable bindings; see http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html
 */
export function setAppInjector(injector: Injector) {
    if (AppInjector) {
        // Should not happen
        console.error('Programming error: AppInjector was already set');
    }
    else {
        AppInjector = injector;
    }
}
```

And then in your `AppModule`, use:

```js
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {setAppInjector} from './app-injector';

export class AppModule {
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        setAppInjector(injector);
    }
}
```

...while in the other classes still use:

```js
import {AppInjector} from './app-injector';
const myService = AppInjector.get(MyService);
```

(There should be no need for manual casting the results; the compiler should know the type of your service.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This doesn't work for me. Still getting the same errors :(

Comment: Then I'd guess the error is not (or no longer) related to using the global `AppInjector`, or you failed to remove the now obsolete import for `AppModule` in your components. Is the error really exactly the same?

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. However I am now struggling to get the tests to play nice, as the base class that retrieves the service is returning null for the HtppClient.

Comment: Thank you, I was going to pull my hair out!