# Is it possible to throw errors inside ngrx-effects without completing the Observable stream?

Tags: angular, error-handling, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Is there any way to use `throw` with an Error object inside ngrx-effects streams without completing the stream?

I've read these great answers on why the stream is being killed by throwing an error:

[@ngrx Effect does not run the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180361/ngrx-effect-does-not-run-the-second-time/44180463#44180463)

[ngrx effects error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685519/ngrx-effects-error-handling/41685689#41685689)

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/646

My question is if I'm implementing the Angular `ErrorHandler` to catch errors, if I'm going to be able to use that with ngrx effects.

```
@Effect()
  loginUserEffect: Observable<loginActions.Actions> = this.actions$
    .ofType(loginActions.LOGIN_USER)
    .map((action: loginActions.LoginUser) => action.payload)
    .mergeMap(payload => {
      return this.loginService
        .authenticate(payload)
        .map(response => new loginActions.LoginUserSuccess(response))
        .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>
          of(new loginActions.LoginUserFailure(error))
        )
  })

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  loginUserEffectSuccess$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(loginActions.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS)
    .do(() => this.router.navigate(['/account-home']))

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  loginUserEffectFailure$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(loginActions.LOGIN_USER_FAILURE)
    .map((action: loginActions.LoginUserFailure) => {
      throw action.payload // Stream completes
  })
```

I imagine I could create some way of dealing with errors that doesn't involve throwing anything, but wanted to make sure I needed to go that route or if there was a way to keep both of them peacefully coexisting.

Currently in my class that implements `ErrorHander`, I have this:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  private messagesService: MessagesService
  private router: Router

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector, // DI workaround (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585902)
    private errorLoggerService: ErrorLoggerService
  ) {
    // DI workaround (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585902)
    setTimeout(() => (this.messagesService = injector.get(MessagesService)))
    setTimeout(() => (this.router = injector.get(Router)))
  }

  handleError(error) {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      this.handleServerError(error)
    } else if (error instanceof ClientError) {
      this.handleClientError(error)
    } else {
      this.handleUnexpectedError(error)
    }
  }
```

Which means I just throw errors and they are handled based on the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to throw an error that will not be caught by the observable and will instead be reported to a global error handler, you have throw the error from outside of the observable's call stack.

You could do something like this:

```ts
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
loginUserEffectFailure$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(loginActions.LOGIN_USER_FAILURE)
  .do(action => setTimeout(() => { throw action.payload; }, 0))
})
```

However, as your effects are in a class that already uses Angular's DI mechanism, I would suggest you instead inject your `GlobalErrorHandler` and call it directly.

Without the `setTimeout` calls I think it would be clearer and easier to test, too.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up creating an Error action:

```
@Effect()
  loginUserEffectFailure$: Observable<
    errorsActions.Actions
  > = this.actions$
    .ofType(loginActions.LOGIN_USER_FAILURE)
    .map(
      (action: loginActions.LoginUserFailure) =>
        new errorsActions.Error(action.payload)
    )
```

and having that call the error handler in a dedicated effect:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  errorEffect$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(errorsActions.ERROR)
    .map((action: errorsActions.Error) =>
      this.clientErrorHandler.handleError(action.payload)
    )
```

I left the global error handler just for unexpected exceptions to be caught and logged.

Comment: That's definitely better that throwing and catching. Another thing to consider is that if you have a standardized naming scheme for your error actions, you could use an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496998/6680611). That is you could use a reducer (or an effect) that checks for actions ending in `_FAILURE` or `_ERROR`, etc.