# Ngrx Store as dependency in providers causes cyclic dependency

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to override default angular `ErrorHandler` by providing factory function which should have ngrx store injected:

```
import { ErrorHandler } from "@angular/core";

[...]

    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useFactory: (store: Store<AppState>) => {
        return Sentry.createErrorHandler({
          showDialog: true,
          dialogOptions: {},
        });
      },
      deps: [Store],
    },
```

but I get cyclic dependency error:

```
main.ts:42 Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for Store. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.js:216)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11434)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11257)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4751)
    at ɵɵinject (core.js:4755)
    at injectArgs (core.js:4832)
    at Object.factory (core.js:11522)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11438)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11257)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4751)
```

How to omit this problem? I need to provide sth from the store to the factory function that creates error handler (`Sentry.createErrorHandler`).

Comment: Have you tried injecting the `Injector` instead of the `Store`? Then, you could use `injector.get(Store)` to get the store, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way Ive found is to implement a custom Error Handler as `ngrx-store` uses Angulars `EventHandler` eg

**SentryErrorHandler**

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/angular";
import { Integrations } from "@sentry/tracing";

@Injectable()
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor() {
    Sentry.init({
      dsn: "https://[your-sentry-dsn-here]",
      integrations: [
       new Integrations.BrowserTracing({
         tracingOrigins: ["localhost", "other-test-urls"],
         routingInstrumentation: Sentry.routingInstrumentation
      })
    ]
  });
}

handleError(error: Error) {
    Sentry.captureException(error);
  }
}
```

then in your `app.module`

```
providers: [
   {
       provide: ErrorHandler,
       useClass: SentryErrorHandler
    }
 ]
```

To test an example would be to create an incorrect url in an `Effect` that calls a service and NOT `catchError` to see if it pops up in Sentry eg

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, 
   private settingsService: settingsService) {

  } 

 loadSettings$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(settingsActions.loadSettings),
    mergeMap(() => this.settingsService.get()
     .pipe(
       map((response) => settingsActions.loadSettingsSuccess({ payload: response})),
      //catchError((error) => of(settingsActions.loadSettingsFailed({ payload: error}))) //commented out should go to Sentry instead
    ))
  ));
}
```

**UPDATE**
Seems the `ErrorHandler` is created very early in the lifecycle before the providers so tried by adding the `Injector` as a constructor parameter

```
@Injectable()
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  //store property to use in handleError
  private get _store() {
   return this.injector.get(Store);
  }

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }.......
```

see this answer [Injecting services in custom ErrorHandler causes "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!" error, how can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585863/injecting-services-in-custom-errorhandler-causes-cannot-instantiate-cyclic-depe)

Comment: Yep, but what I wanted to do is to provide Store in order to retrieve some user data and prefill the sentry dialog with it.

Comment: I had this issue while trying to inject `Store` in my custom title strategy ([see this for reference](https://dev.to/brandontroberts/setting-page-titles-natively-with-the-angular-router-393j)). You saved my day, thanks!